# Ellipsizing list joins, Pythonically

Tags: python, string, list, join

I learned about list comprehensions a few days ago, and now I think I’ve gone a little crazy with them, trying to make them solve *all the problems*. Perhaps I don’t truly understand them yet, or I just don’t know enough Python yet to make them both powerful *and* simple. This problem has occupied me for a while now, and I’d appreciate any input.

### The Problem

In Python, join a list of strings `words` into a single string `excerpt` that satisfies these conditions:

- a single space separates elements
- the final length of `excerpt` does not exceed integer `maximum_length`
- if all elements of `words` are not in `excerpt`, append an ellipsis character `…` to `excerpt`
- only whole elements of `words` appear in `excerpt`

### The Ugly Solution

```py
words = ('Your mother was a hamster and your ' +
         'father smelled of elderberries!').split()
maximum_length = 29
excerpt = ' '.join(words) if len(' '.join(words)) <= maximum_length else \
          ' '.join(words[:max([n for n in range(0, len(words)) if \
                               len(' '.join(words[:n]) + '\u2026') <= \
                               maximum_length])]) + '\u2026'
print(excerpt)      # Your mother was a hamster…
print(len(excerpt)) # 26
```

Yup, that works. `Your mother was a hamster and` fits in 29, but leaves no room for the ellipsis. But boy is it ugly. I can break it up a little:

```
words = ('Your mother was a hamster and your ' +
         'father smelled of elderberries!').split()
maximum_length = 29
excerpt = ' '.join(words)
if len(excerpt) > maximum_length:
    maximum_words = max([n for n in range(0, len(words)) if \
                         len(' '.join(words[:n]) + '\u2026') <= \
                         maximum_length])
    excerpt = ' '.join(words[:maximum_words]) + '\u2026'
print(excerpt)  # 'Your mother was a hamster…'
```

But now I’ve made a variable I’m never going to use again. Seems like a waste. And it hasn’t really made anything prettier or easier to understand.

Is there a nicer way to do this that I just haven’t seen yet?

Comment: it looks like you're right about going to crazy about the list comprehension. remember the zen of python: "3. Simple is better than complex". it took me 10 seconds to understand the problem, but it took 5 minutes to understand your code. don't be too frugal about lines and variables. it's not python you need to impress, but the guy who will maintain your code later on.

Comment: If I had to solve this problem using listcomps, I'd use the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/textwrap.html) module.  (But that wouldn't use listcomps! --ed.  Reread my first sentence carefully. --dsm)

Comment: @DSM - `textwrap.shorten` looks like it does exactly what I want it to do, provided none of the elements in `words` contain spaces, in which case I could end up with a partial element. I didn't specify that possibility in the question, though, as it only just occurred to me reading the answers.

Answer (score 2):

see my comment about why "simple is better than complex"

that said, here's a suggestion

```
l = 'Your mother was a hamster and your father smelled of elderberries!'

last_space = l.rfind(' ', 0, 29)

suffix = ""
if last_space < 29:
  suffix = "..."

print l[:last_space]+suffix
```

this is not 100% what you need, but rather easy to extend

Comment: The index of `last_space` will always be less than 29 when you're only searching through `l[0:29]`...

Comment: you're right, actually it needs to be checked for `-1` which means "not found". I only wanted to suggest a direction, not a full solution.

Comment: does not work if the string is shorter than 29 it will simply trim the last word

Comment: a working solution would be `if len(l) > 29: print l[:l.rfind(' ', 0, 27)]+'...'`

Answer (score 0):

My humble opinion is that you are right in that list comprehension is not necessary for this task. I would first get all words in a list with the split, then maybe do a while loop that remove words one at a time from the end of the list until len(' '.join(list)) < maximum_length.

I would also shorten the maximum_length by 3 (the length of the elipses) and after the while loop ends, add the "..." as the last element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim the `excerpt` down to the `maximum_length`. Then, use `rsplit` to remove the last space and append on the ellipsis:

```
def append_ellipsis(words, length=29):
    excerpt = ' '.join(words)[:length]

    # If you are using Python 3.x then you can instead of the line below,
    # pass `maxsplit=1` to `rsplit`. Below is the Python 2.x version.
    return excerpt.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + '\u2026'

words = ('Your mother was a hamster and your ' +
         'father smelled of elderberries!').split()

result = append_ellipsis(words)
print(result)
print(len(result))
```

Comment: You should be able to use `rsplit` whether or not the last character is a space.

Comment: @Peter [The Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) shows that `rsplit` takes keyword arguments (at least as far back as 2.6 and as current as the dev 3.5)

Comment: `rsplit` does take arguments in 2.x, but it does not take _keyword_ arguments - you have to use `rsplit(' ', 1)` or `rsplit(None, 1)`.